# How to implement Cocos2D?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, implementation

I have downloaded the latest cocos2d from their site, and I have unzipped it. Now I am confused exactly how to implement it into an already existing project. What files do I drag over and is there anything else I have to do besides that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link cocos2d into your project as shown [here](http://www.tinytimgames.com/2011/07/22/cocos2d-and-arc/). He uses a special version that supports arc, but it works in exactly the same way with the original version. Then in a next step make sure that you import all the important libraries:

- QuartzCore.framework
- OpenGLES.framework
- AVFoundation.framework
- UIKit.framework
- Foundation.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework

If you use sound you also will need:

- OpenAL.framework
- AudioToolbox.framework
- libcocosDenshion.a

Now you need to set up a rootview that supports OpenGL. Look at the Hello World example how they did this there. You should now be able to implement and display Cocos2d scenes on screen.

Comment: Thanks for the info, everything seems to be going ok so far, now with the Root View, should I just copy over the RootViewController.h and .m into my project?

Comment: Yes you can do that. You will also need the GameConfig.h file. Then finally you need to make some changes to the AppDelegate to load the RootViewController or you can also just copy the AppDelegate from HelloWorld.

Comment: Ok I will copy e everything except the appdelegate because I already have my own appdelegate that's finished coding in UIKit. I'll just copy the code in it.

Comment: Also it says to literally drag the cocos2d-ios .xcodeproj into my project directly, is that what I am supposed to do ?

Comment: Yes. This will insert a reference to cocos2d-ios in your project. It will not copy the project. So everytime you change one of the settings in cocos2d-ios projects all other projects that hold references to it will automatically have them as well.

Comment: And last question, since I only want to use Cocos2D in one UIView (EAGLView), do I still have to load the RootViewController into my app delegate? Or how do I go from here to make Cocos2D in only one of my views?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here straight from the source:

[Cocos2D tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/582)

Comment: So pretty much I copy over the group, "Cocos2D sources"?

Comment: copying the sources will also work, but will give you a lot of problems whenever you want to update to a newer version. Using a static library is better for this. Also you do not waste disk space always copying the same files.